# MySQL pivot select 2 SUMs

Tags: mysql

I have two sum functions being done in the same table with the following query:

```
select sum(a), sum(b) from table
```

resulting in the following output:

```
SUM a    SUM b
1312     2121
```

I want the output to show the labels in the left column and results in the right column i.e.:

```
SUM a    1312
SUM b    2121
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use union

```
select 'SUM a' my_text, col_sum_a
from my_table 
union 
select  'SUM b', col_sum_b
from my_table
```

Comment: Can you please explain where "my_text" comes from?

Comment: The union append the result of a select to another select  ( the two select must have the corresponding numner of column and data type)